# Azure Storage Server Latency experienced when reading the same blob multiple times

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using an Azure Storage Account to deliver images to a client service and we are experiencing latency for a couple of days, with download times jumping from a few ms to a few seconds **for the same blob being downloaded**

I read on MSDN [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting?tabs=dotnet#metrics-show-high-AverageServerLatency) that it can happen when the same blob is queried for reading over and over, which is our case.

Has anyone experienced the same issue before? Can it jump by x 1000 randomly ?

And, what would be the easiest way to fix this problem? It is compromising performances of the client system, and since there is only one client machine located into the same Datacenter, it doesn't really make sense (from my point of view) to set up a CDN.

A potential mitigation is to set up a cache from the client propsepctive as well, but this is a bit complex due to the amount of data being queried and I'd like to solve this issue from the Storage-Side directly.

We use :

- A Premium Storage Account
- Locally redundant
- And a BlockBlobStorage Account Kind

Thanks for your help.

[image: Storage Log for a given Blob being read]

Comment: There's really no specific programming question here but... seems like you've already answered your own question (enabling CDN). Not sure why you immediately dismissed that option...

Comment: Also: Please only post formatted text, not images of text. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for lots of reasons why this is important.

Comment: @DavidMakogon from my understanding, a CDN is made to deliver efficiently content to multiple clients around the globe, not to a single client next door. 
Point taken for the image, it is no text though, just showing the high variance of the download time to illustrate my problem.

Comment: @DavidMakogon since you work at MSFT, do you confirm that this is an expected behavior from the Azure Storage? Does it seem correct to you to get this variance?  Thanks!